# iOS 16 - has anything been updated that would remove compatibility to Mojave?

Tags: ios, mojave, compatibility

Similarly to how Reminders was 'upgraded' at iOS 13 - see [Old reminders are gone from macOS 10.14.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371072/old-reminders-are-gone-from-macos-10-14-6)
Has there been any further significant compatibility change in iOS 16?

Background: My phone is new, my Mac is old. My main workhorse Mac must remain on Mojave to retain compatibility to a significant amount of pro audio gear which will no longer function in Catalina or newer. I will not be replacing this rig until absolutely forced. An iOS update doesn't qualify as sufficient 'force'.
If there are show-stopping incompatibilities I will let the phone OS fall behind too.

<sup>I have no use for Reminders, so this didn't prevent my updating to iOS 13 at the time.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Home architecture

iOS 16.2 introduced the new Home architecture. If you choose to opt in to the new architecture, which is neither enforced nor available at the time of writing (it is ‘temporarily removed’), you will no longer be able to control your Home from Macs not running at least macOS 13.1.

> Any device that is connected to an upgraded home and not running the latest software will lose access to the home until the device is updated.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT213481

### Advanced Data Protection for iCloud

iOS 16.2 introduced the option to enable Advanced Data Protection for iCloud. If you choose to opt in, you will be unable to access your iCloud account from Macs running not running at least macOS 13.1.

> You must also update all of your Apple devices to a software version that supports this feature.

If you enable this feature but need to access iCloud data from a device running older OS, you can enable ‘Access iCloud Data on the Web’ and use an updated device to provide the keys to decrypt the data:

> You have the option to turn on data access on iCloud.com, which allows Apple and the web browser you're using to have temporary access to data-specific encryption keys provided by your device to decrypt and view your information.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202303#advanced

Comment: Thank you. That sounds promising - two things i don't need. I'll hang on a while before marking as accepted, just in case anyone else manages to find a show-stopper.

Comment: Updated last night - nothing bad so far ;))