# iOS 17 - has anything been updated that would remove compatibility to Mojave?

Tags: ios, mojave, compatibility

This is literally the same question as [iOS 16 - has anything been updated that would remove compatibility to Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453724/ios-16-has-anything-been-updated-that-would-remove-compatibility-to-mojave) just with 16 updated to 17. IMO the two should remain separate questions.

Similarly to how Reminders was 'upgraded' at iOS 13 - see [Old reminders are gone from macOS 10.14.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371072/old-reminders-are-gone-from-macos-10-14-6)
Has there been any further significant compatibility change in iOS 17?

Background: My phone is new, my Mac is old. My main workhorse Mac must remain on Mojave to retain compatibility to a significant amount of pro audio gear which will no longer function in Catalina or newer. I will not be replacing this rig until absolutely forced. An iOS update doesn't qualify as sufficient 'force'.
If there are show-stopping incompatibilities I will let the phone OS fall behind too.

<sup>I have no use for Reminders, so this didn't prevent my updating to iOS 13 at the time.</sup>

Comment: Yea, I would have stayed on iOS 16 myself (my Mac are both Monterey) except for the remote exploit Apple isn't patching in iOS 16 for phones that can run iOS 17.  I spent an hour or so going through all the new iOS 17 idiocies and disabling what I could, but you can't lose the disaster they made out of the Phone and Contacts apps.